# Parsing json value in Python

Tags: python, json

I am receiving a json from a web page request.

```
    {
  "ChildAvailability": {
    "ChildrenStatus": "Available",
    "ChildrenTitle": "4 years to 18 years",
    "MinimumAgeErrorMessage": "Due to safety issues we do not allow any baby under the age of 1 year old at the time of sailing. For this cruise, this means any baby born on or after 05 Dec 2015. Inappropriately adding guests, could result in your booking being cancelled.",
    "InfantAvailability": 14,
    "InfantBirthdayRange": {
      "Item1": "2013-12-06",
      "Item2": "2015-12-05"
    },
    "ChildrenBirthdayRange": {
      "Item1": "1998-12-06",
      "Item2": "2013-12-05"
    },
    "InfantStatus": "Limited",
    "InfantTitle": "12 months to 3 years",
    "OverallAvailability": 156,
    "VoyageCode": "P652"
  },
  "EligibleChildFareThreshold": "2003-12-05",
  "Items": [
    {
      "Fare": {
        "AdditionalPromoCodes": [],
        "CabinSize": null,
        "DisplayWasPrice": false,
        "GradeCode": "",
        "IsDiscreet": false,
        "IsObstructed": false,
        "IsPremium": false,
        "NumberOfPax": 0,
        "Price": -1.0,
        "PricePerPerson": -1.0,
        "PricePerPersonPerNight": -1.0,
        "PriceWas": -1.0,
        "PromoCode": "",
        "RoomTypeCode": null,
        "Usps": []
      },
      "HasAvailability": false,
      "CanHaveObstructed": false,
      "CanHavePremium": false,
      "RoomTypeCode": "I"
    },
    {
      "CanHaveObstructed": true,
      "CanHavePremium": false,
      "Fare": {
        "AdditionalPromoCodes": null,
        "CabinSize": "TWIN",
        "DisplayWasPrice": true,
        "GradeCode": "OV",
        "IsDiscreet": false,
        "IsObstructed": true,
        "IsPremium": false,
        "NumberOfPax": 2,
        "Price": 1398.000000,
        "PricePerPerson": 699.000000,
        "PricePerPersonPerNight": 87.0,
        "PriceWas": 2908.000000,
        "PromoCode": "FL9",
        "RoomTypeCode": "O",
        "Usps": []
      },
      "HasAvailability": true,
      "RoomTypeCode": "O"
    },
    {
      "Fare": {
        "AdditionalPromoCodes": [],
        "CabinSize": null,
        "DisplayWasPrice": false,
        "GradeCode": "",
        "IsDiscreet": false,
        "IsObstructed": false,
        "IsPremium": false,
        "NumberOfPax": 0,
        "Price": -1.0,
        "PricePerPerson": -1.0,
        "PricePerPersonPerNight": -1.0,
        "PriceWas": -1.0,
        "PromoCode": "",
        "RoomTypeCode": null,
        "Usps": []
      },
      "HasAvailability": false,
      "CanHaveObstructed": false,
      "CanHavePremium": false,
      "RoomTypeCode": "B"
    },
    {
      "Fare": {
        "AdditionalPromoCodes": [],
        "CabinSize": null,
        "DisplayWasPrice": false,
        "GradeCode": "",
        "IsDiscreet": false,
        "IsObstructed": false,
        "IsPremium": false,
        "NumberOfPax": 0,
        "Price": -1.0,
        "PricePerPerson": -1.0,
        "PricePerPersonPerNight": -1.0,
        "PriceWas": -1.0,
        "PromoCode": "",
        "RoomTypeCode": null,
        "Usps": []
      },
      "HasAvailability": false,
      "CanHaveObstructed": false,
      "CanHavePremium": false,
      "RoomTypeCode": "M"
    }
  ],
  "QuoteId": null
}
```

i am having problems getting the "Items" child. So far i did this:

```
price_item_list = cruise_price_data["Items"]
```

and if i print `price_item_list` i get this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fixxxer/PycharmProjects/POCruses/main.py", line 94, in <module>
    print(price_item_list["RoomTypeCode"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I am thinking this must be some conversion mistake. Where is my mistake?

Comment: You aren't printing the `price_item_list`, you are printing `price_item_list["RoomTypeCode"]`, which you can can't do. It's not a dictionary

Comment: Try `price_item_list[0]['Fare']['RoomTypeCode']`, i.e. the code of the **first item** in that list.

Comment: `Items` is a list. You will have to handle it like on. Either you iterate over it or you just get one item: `cruise_price_data["Items"][0]`

Comment: @cricket_007 fixed, thanks

Comment: so why the downvote?

Comment: @fixxxera yes, it is about conversion issue, you need first to convert your json to python object, take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to convert your json data to a Python object like below:

```
import json

data = json.loads(your_json)
```

Now, you should be able to iterate over `data`:

```
for item in data['Items']:
    print(item['RoomTypeCode'])
    # ...
```

Comment: You missed the `Fare`

Comment: @cricket_007 `RoomTypeCode` is at the same level as `Fare`

Comment: Oh. There's two... That's confusing

Comment: You're right, but I just want to show that he needs to use `json.loads()`, after that he can read that without problem.

Comment: `cruise_price_data` is already a parsed json string, otherwise the traceback would be different